# Kubuntu LUKS on USB boots internal disk after password prompt

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, dual-boot, luks

I have an install of Kubuntu 22.04 on a USB connected NVMe drive.  This drive has the root filesystem encrypted with LUKS.  On all but one machine I have tried, this OS boots just fine and lets me use it on any machine.

I have a Dell Precision 7750 that has 4 internal NVMe drives. One of them is also Kubuntu 22.04 without LUKS. Another is the OEM Windows 10 RE.  The last two are ext4 data disks.  When I try to boot the LUKS USB OS on this laptop (after modifying the UEFI boot order or using boot order override key), I get the LUKS password prompt at initial boot like normal.  Unfortunately, I get booted to the OS on the internal NVMe drive, not the decrypted LUKS volume's OS.

How do I fix this?  Why would only this one machine have this behavior (something in the Dell UEFI)?  I just want to boot to the internal drive OS when the USB drive is not plugged in and then boot to the USB OS when it is.

Comment: Did you clone anything with dd, so there could be a duplicate UUID issue? With multiple Ubuntu installs it can also be a collision of duplicate LVM/VG names. Check with `lsblk`, `blkid`, `pvs`, `vgs`, ... also check `cat /proc/cmdline` that you're booting the correct kernel with correct parameters...

Comment: I did not clone these disks, so the UUIDs should not have collided.  I will check the LVM/VG names as you suggested to see if that is the culprit.

Comment: @frostschutz I believe you have nailed it.  Both installs have root=/dev/vgkubuntu/root in the output from `cat /proc/cmdline`.  My other Kubuntu box that doesn't have this issue has root=UUID=<partition UUID>.  How do I change the value used, so that I can point it at the UUID of the decrypted ext4 partition inside of the LUKS volume?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: use root=UUID=rootfsuuid *and also* rename the VG so its unique and doesn't clash with existing installs